# kafka-producer-perf-test.sh how many producers?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Hello I am using the kafka-producer-perf-test.sh on the latest Kafka version but I am not able to figure, if it is possible to configure how many producers threads that are created?

Answer (score 1):

The `kafka-producer-perf-test.sh` tool (`org.apache.kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance`) only starts a single Producer. This is not configurable.

The old ProducerPerformance tool (`kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance`) which is still bundled in the Kafka distribution was able to start many threads.

To run it:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance
```